# How to upload image to firebase storage for Editor.js?

Tags: javascript, buffer, firebase-storage, editorjs

I am trying to add image upload functionality in Editor.js by using backend file uploader endpoint. In the backend, I am uploading this file to firebase storage. But actually I am able to extract the file. I tried many ways but it didn't work

Is there any other method to add image upload functionality to `editor.js`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using editorjs also, thanks for the answer. Here's my solutions to the problem:

```
uploadByFile(file : File) {
            const path = `post/${Date.now()}_${file.name}`;
            const ref = that.afStorage.ref(path);
            const task = that.afStorage.upload(path, file);
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              task.snapshotChanges()
                .pipe(
                  finalize( () => {
                    ref.getDownloadURL()
                      .subscribe(url => {
                        console.log(url);
                        let res = {
                          success: 1,
                          file: {
                            url : url
                          }
                        }
                        resolve(res);
                      },error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        reject(error);
                      })
                  }))
                .subscribe( url => {
                  if(url){
                    console.log(url);
                  }
                })
            })
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

This was exactly what I needed to get this resolved so thank you Sachin Kumar.  Here is a full working example but note that you will need to fill in your Firebase settings in the image.css file or you wont connect to firebase storage.  I did not take example to saving content as I did not want to be too long but this should get you started.

I was testing the embed so I included the code for embed which will allow you to copy a youtube video URL and embed a youtube video by just including the embed js and configuration.  Again no save yet but pretty straightforward.

test.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html  >
    <head>
        <!-- Add editorJS via CDN -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/editorjs@latest"></script> 
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/header@latest"></script> 
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/list@latest"></script> 
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/embed@latest"></script> 
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/image@2.3.0"></script> 
        
        <!-- Add Firebase via CDN-->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.3/firebase-app.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.3/firebase-storage.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>EditorJs</h4>
        <div id="editorjs" style="background-color: grey;" ></div>
        <!-- Add the javascript for Image component and Firebase Storage -->
        <script src="image.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the image.js file (remember to update firebase config):

```
    var firebaseConfig = {
/* Enter your firebase Config settings here or this wont work */
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db=firebase.firestore();
const ImageTool = window.ImageTool;

const editor = new EditorJS({
    holder: 'editorjs',
    placeholder: 'Enter Card Content',
    tools: {
        header: {
            class: Header,
            inlineToolbar: ['link']
        },
        list: {
            class: List,
            inlineToolbar: ['link','bold']
        },
        embed: {
            class: Embed,
            inlineToolbar: false,
            config: {
                services: {
                    youtube: true,
                    coub: true
                }
            },
        },
        image: {
            class: ImageTool,
            config: {
                    uploader: {
                        async uploadByFile(file) {
                            let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
                            let imagesRef = storageRef.child('EditorJS').child('images/'+ file.name);
                            let metadata = {
                                contentType: 'image/jpeg'
                            };
                            let uploadTask = await imagesRef.put(file, metadata);
                            const downloadURL = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
                            return {
                                success: 1,
                                file: {
                                    url: downloadURL
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }               
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found another way of doing this. Editor.js provides a way in which we can add `UploadByFile` method on the client side. And Firebase storage works fine on the client side. Here is the code

```
config: {
    uploader: {
        async uploadByFile(file) {
            var storageRef = storage.ref();
            var imagesRef = storageRef.child('EditorJS').child('images/'+ file.name);
            var metadata = {
                contentType: 'image/jpeg'
            };
            var uploadTask = await imagesRef.put(file, metadata);
            console.log("Uploaded successfully!", uploadTask);
            const downloadURL = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
            console.log(downloadURL);
            return {
                success: 1,
                file: {
                    url: downloadURL
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add this config to image object within editor.js implementation.